# Navigating a .txt file with a two dimensional array

Tags: java, arrays

For this assignment I am to read a .txt file and recursively navigate the maze it produces(I'll provide an example below) navigate it and print it. I have the navigation down and my partner is making the print method. However, I am having problems determining the start position of the maze. In the maze the start will be signified with an s.  It's easier to explain with a picture so I'll provide that now

```
5    
#####
#s.##
##..#
###.#
#g..#
```

The number at the top determines the size of the array(we have to make them square).  The '#' is a wall, the '.' is an available path, and the 'g' is a goal.  Right now what my problem is, is finding the coordinate of the s so that I know where to start my maze at.  Below will be the file chooser class(where the problem is) and the class to navigate the maze(it works but I thought I'd include it in case anyone was curious

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
    {
        FileReader myReader;
        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
        if(chooser.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
        {
            File myFile = chooser.getSelectedFile();
            myReader = new FileReader(myFile);   
            Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(myReader);
            String placeHolder = myScanner.nextLine();
            int arrayThings = Integer.parseInt(placeHolder);
            char[][] maze = new char[arrayThings][arrayThings];
            int rows = 0;
            int columns = 0;
            for(int i = 0; i < maze.length(); i++)
            {
                if (maze[rows][columns] == 's' || maze[rows][columns] =='S')
                {
                    FindPath(maze[arrayThings][arrayThings],rows,columns);
                }                    
            }               
            myReader.close();
        }           
    }
```

I'm not entirely sure how to navigate my maze to find the 's'.  And now here is the FindPath method

```
public static boolean FindPath(char[][] maze,int x,int y)
    {
        try
        {
            if (maze[x][y] == 'g' || maze[x][y] =='G')
            {
                System.out.println("The maze was printed");  //Replace with print method
                return true;
            }
            else if (maze[x][y] == '#' || maze[x][y] == '?' || maze[x][y] == 'P')
                return false;
            else 
            {
                maze[x][y] = 'P';
                System.out.println("The maze was printed"); //Replace with print method
                if(MazeSolver.FindPath(maze,x,y-1)== true)
                    return true;
                else if(MazeSolver.FindPath(maze,x+1,y)== true)
                    return true;
                else if(MazeSolver.FindPath(maze,x,y+1)== true)
                    return true;
                else if(MazeSolver.FindPath(maze,x-1,y)== true)
                    return true;
                maze[x][y] = '?';
                return false;
            }
        } 
        catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException myEx)
        {
            return false;
        }        
    }
```

Comment: It's a bad idea to have you're recursion hinge on a `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: looks like in your for loop you keep checking maze[rows][columns] and they are 0 every time the loop goes

Comment: Yeah that for loop was mainly a placeholder for something I thought might work eventually once I figure out how to properly navigate it

Comment: Agreed with @jonny, that exception handling made my eyebrows twitch. You are definitely going to get marked down for that one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to initialize your maze before that :

```
for(int row = 0; row < maze.length; row++)
     {
         for(int col = 0; col < maze[0].length;col++){
             if(maze[row][col] == 's'){
                 System.out.println("x :" + row + " y : " + col);
             }
         }
     }
```

it's not what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

**There are two things to look at:**

**First**
The following code runs through the two dimensional array searching for the character `s` after the two dimensional array has been filled.

```
for(int row = 0; row < maze.length; row++)
{
    for(int col = 0; col < maze[0].length;col++){
        if(maze[row][col] == 's'){
            System.out.println("x :" + row + " y : " + col);
        }
    }
}
```

Why not find and keep track of the character `s` while filling the two dimensional array? This would save you from iterating over the two dimensional array again.

```
row = 0;
maze = new char[arraySize][arraySize];
while(input.hasNextLine()) {
    String lineHolder = input.nextLine();
    // get the char array from the String
    maze[row] = lineHolder.toCharArray();
    if(lineHolder.indexOf('s') != -1) {
        // start row equals the current row
        sRow = row;
        // start column equals the index/column of 's'
        sCol = lineHolder.indexOf('s');
    }
    row = row + 1;
}
```

**Second**
Instead of hinging your recursion with a try catch block, just implement bounds checking.

```
// maze bounds checking, recursion no longer hinges on an exception
// being thrown
if(y < 0 || x < 0 || y > maze.length-1 || x > maze[0].length-1) {
    return false;
}
```

---

I've included the following working code to give context to the information provided above.

### Working Code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFileChooser chooser = null;
    Scanner input = null;
    int arraySize = 0;
    char[][] maze;
    int row = 0;
    int sRow = 0;
    int sCol = 0;

    chooser = new JFileChooser();

    if (chooser.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        try {
            input = new Scanner(chooser.getSelectedFile());
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("Exiting...");
        System.exit(0);
    }

    if(input.hasNextLine()) {
        arraySize = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine().trim());
    }

    row = 0;
    maze = new char[arraySize][arraySize];
    while(input.hasNextLine()) {
        String lineHolder = input.nextLine();
        // get the char array from the String
        maze[row] = lineHolder.toCharArray();
        if(lineHolder.indexOf('s') != -1) {
            // start row equals the current row
            sRow = row;
            // start column equals the index/column of 's'
            sCol = lineHolder.indexOf('s');
        }
        row = row + 1;
    }
    input.close();

    System.out.println("The maze has been read in:");
    printMaze(maze);

    FindPath(maze, sCol, sRow);
}

public static boolean FindPath(char[][] maze, int x, int y) {
    // maze bounds checking, recursion no longer hinges on an exception
    // being thrown
    if(y < 0 || x < 0 || y > maze.length-1 || x > maze[0].length-1) {
        return false;
    }

    if (Character.toLowerCase(maze[x][y]) == 'g') {
        System.out.println("The maze has been solved:");
        maze[x][y] = 'P';
        printMaze(maze);
        return true;
    }

    if(maze[x][y] == '.' || maze[x][y] == 's') {
        maze[x][y] = 'P';
        System.out.println("Solving...");
        printMaze(maze);

        if (FindPath(maze, x, y - 1)) {
            return true;
        } else if (FindPath(maze, x + 1, y)) {
            return true;
        } else if (FindPath(maze, x, y + 1)) {
            return true;
        } else if (FindPath(maze, x - 1, y)) {
            return true;
        }

        return true;
    } else {
        // if maze[x][y] equals # or P then return false
        return false;
    }
}

public static void printMaze(char[][] maze) {
    for(int r = 0; r < maze.length; r++) {
        for(int c = 0; c < maze[r].length; c++) {
            System.out.print(maze[r][c]);
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
    }
}
```

### Output

```
The maze has been read in:
#####
#s.##
##..#
###.#
#g..#
Solving...
#####
#P.##
##..#
###.#
#g..#
Solving...
#####
#PP##
##..#
###.#
#g..#
Solving...
#####
#PP##
##P.#
###.#
#g..#
Solving...
#####
#PP##
##PP#
###.#
#g..#
Solving...
#####
#PP##
##PP#
###P#
#g..#
Solving...
#####
#PP##
##PP#
###P#
#g.P#
Solving...
#####
#PP##
##PP#
###P#
#gPP#
The maze has been solved:
#####
#PP##
##PP#
###P#
#PPP#
```